# Regular expression/Replace method Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the pattern to be the following

```
var pattern = /[%25]+/g;//It matches against any encoded percent sign
url = url.replace(pattern,'%');//Replace with only a percent sign
```

Problem is that it also recongnizes pattern such as **%2** which it should not do, it should only recognize **%25**

As it is now it interfers with my encoded space signs (**%20**) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Do you have a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It also matches `2` and `55` and `%%%25252`. Please give some more examples of what it should and/or should not match. (Unless you mean **only** `%25`? Then loose the brackets...)

Comment: Then loose the brackets it is. Thanks =)

Comment: Read a regexp tutorial. The meaning of brackets is one of the first  things you'll learn. What did you think they were supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a simple literal for this:

```
url = url.replace(/%25/g, '%');
```

The `[...]` construct introduces a character class, which you don't want here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid replacing `%255`:

```
url = url.replace(/%25\b/g, '%');
```

Where `\b`  is a word boundary that assumes there're no digits after `%25`.

Comment: Not so sure about the need for a `\b` ... `%25`, for example, will be encoded as `%2525`. A global replace will only replace everything once, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jongware: It depends if you want to replace it or not. Do you want `%2555` becomes `%55`?